# Margin auto container combined with a flexbox section content

Tags: css, flexbox, containers, margins

So i made some tests with a container with a fixed width but i want to use flexbox too.

So i want to make a webpage with all elements being inside the container and i combine the section with flexbox too.

Is this a correct way of creating the layout? Or i should remove the .container and only using flexbox?

Markup:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: normal 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}

#showcase {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.showcase-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
  <div class="container showcase-content">

    <div class="box">
      <h4>Box 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h4>Box 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h4>Box 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h4>Box 4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h4>Box 5</h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide a wireframe of the final layout?

Comment: What is your desired layout ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/grecualexx/pen/NJmJJa 
 
Something like this and adding flexbox too.
Same width container layout.

Comment: For what exactly do you want to use flexbox? Your codepen seems to do it without.

Comment: there you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgbPXq `flex-direction: column` maybe what you are searching for...

Comment: Well if i use the display: flex property on the .container parent everything is messed up. But if i add both .container and another flex-container class on the same div is ok? Is this a right way of doing things? This is what i mean.